# Redshift stv_wlm_query_state.state: QUEUED vs QUEUEDWAITING

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

In redshift `stv_wlm_query_state` system table, what are the differences between `QUEUED` state and `QUEUEDWAITING` state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not seen an exact and authoritative set of definitions for queue states published but I have a general understanding that has been useful to me.  When a query is submitted it needs to be processed through many steps like compiling, running and returning data.  These are all reflected in queue states but there is also time before and between these steps as the query progresses.  QUEUED just means that the query is in the queue process but not in another defined state.

Since parallel execution of queries is limited by the WLM and the number of slots available there is a defined state for queries that are waiting on other queries to finish before they can be executed.  This specific waiting-for-an-execution-slot state is QUEUEDWAITING.  This is generally the most common place for significant waiting to occur and is directly optimizable through the WLM (but possibly not fixed).  Delays caused by a flurry of very complex queries needing to be compiled and optimized by the leader would not create QUEUEDWAITING states but these could just show up as QUEUED state.

This is my working understanding based on experience.  If someone posts an authoritative set of definitions for queue states I'll be as interested as you are.